# EF Core 5 - "'Property' invalid inside 'Include' operation since it does not represent a property access"

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, fluentvalidation, sql-view

These are the 2 entities i created, they represent views in my database:

ItemTPP08:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Data;
using System;
namespace ApplicationCore.Entities

{
    [Keyless]
    public class ItemTPP08
    {
        public long Fecha { get; set; }
        public string NroPedido { get; set; }
        public string Estado { get; set; }
        public string Familia { get; set; }
        public string CodigoProducto { get; set; }
        public string Producto { get; set; }
        public double Cantidad { get; set; }
        public string UnidadComercial { get; set; }
        public string Unidad { get; set; }
        public string IdUnidadComercial { get; set; }
        public string IdUnidad { get; set; }

        public ICollection<P08Teradata> Teradata { get; set; }
  


    }
}
```

P08Teradata:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
#pragma warning disable 1591
namespace ApplicationCore.Entities
{
    [Keyless]
    public class P08Teradata
    {
        public string NroPedido { get; set; }
        public string cmps1 { get; set; }
        public string cmpsa { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }
        public DateTime? FechaActualizacion { get; set; }
        public bool Habilitacion { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ItemTPP08> ItemTPP08 { get; set; }

    }

}
```

**Both entities would be linked by the "NroPedido" property. A "ItemTPP08" item can have many "P08Teradata" Items and viceversa.**

This is my FluentValidation code (Maybe is not necessary to show it but just in case):

```
 public class IOP18ARContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            
           
            modelBuilder.Entity<P08Teradata>().HasNoKey().ToView("Teradata", "dbo");

            modelBuilder.Entity<ItemTPP08>().HasNoKey().ToView("TrackingProductos", "dbo");

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }

        public DbSet<P08Teradata> P08Teradata { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ItemTPP08> ItemsTPP08 { get; set; }
        

    }
```

Now i want to try this query:

```
   var query = dbIOP.ItemsTPP08.Include(p => p.Teradata).Where(c => c.NroPedido == "827556284").ToList();
```

But it throws this error:

> The expression 'p.Teradata' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation,
> since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To
> target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t =>
> ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as
> Derived).MyProperty').

This is the stack trace:

> 'System.InvalidOperationException' en
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll: 'The expression 'p.Teradata' is
> invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a
> property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared
> on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the
> 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection
> navigation access can be filtered by composing Where,
> OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For
> more information on including related data, see
> [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.'](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.%27)    en
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.PopulateIncludeTree(IncludeTreeNode
> includeTreeNode, Expression expression, Boolean setLoaded)    en
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.ProcessInclude(NavigationExpansionExpression
> source, Expression expression, Boolean thenInclude, Boolean setLoaded)
> en
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> methodCallExpression)    en
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression
> methodCallExpression)    en
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.Expand(Expression
> query)    en
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression
> query)    en
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression
> query)    en
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression
> query)    en
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression
> query, Boolean async)    en
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase
> database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)    en
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0() en Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)    en
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression
> query)    en
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
> expression)    en
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator() en System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)   en System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    en
> Infrastructure.Data.TrackingProductoRepository.CProductosP08(List`1 cuits, List`1 idsFamilias, List`1 idsProvincias, Int64 nroFechaDesde, Int64 nroFechaHasta, List`1 segmentosCuits) en
> C:\Users\EPUTU\Source\repos\LOYAL _
> IOP18\APP\Code\Productor\APP\Code\Infrastructure\Data\TrackingProductoRepository.cs:
> línea 843

As i understand, the error is asking me to cast the property inside the 'Include', so i tried doing this:

```
var query = dbIOP.ItemsTPP08.Include(p => (p as ItemTPP08).Teradata).Where(c => c.NroPedido == "827556284").ToList();
```

But it throws the same error again.

What exactly am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You may need to make that Teradata property (and other navigation properties) `virtual`

Comment: It looks like your many-to-many relationship isn't being picked up by convention. I suspect [EF Core needs an intermediate table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) to link the records together.

Comment: If both of these entities are marked as keyless, start by explaining how these two entities are actually related to one another, and then look at what you've told EF about that relationship through configuration.  EF can work out basic relationships by convention, but for a many-to-many relationship between tables for example it is expecting to know where to look for a linking table... This just looks like two arbitrary views you want to somehow have it work out how to relate to one another.